# Which Google rest api is used for searching all address possible for taxi application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

As i am creating application like uber ola and using autocomplete api for address this one https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json which is not return all location such as search Gwalior railway station but it does-not show right prediction.I want to search all address search like we do in google maps.Kindly help me which api should i use to achieve from any google rest api.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Places API of Google.

Here is an example for search

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=railway+station+in+gwalior&key=<YourKey>
```

The above API will provide you the paginated results in size of 20 and along with details of each. If you need further details you can use the following API along with the places ID which is returned from the above API response.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=<getThisFromResponseOfPreviousAPI>&fields=name,formatted_address,address_component,geometry&key=<YourKey>
```